# Xamarin, getting value of slider from another class

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have some problem with geting value of slider which is binded to Temp_Mash_value.

```
<Slider x:Name="Temp_Mash" Margin="20,5,20,0" MaximumTrackColor="DarkGray" MinimumTrackColor="Gray" ThumbColor="Black" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding Temp_Mash_value}"
```

When I'm on ContentPage with class Mash I can change the value for example to 45 without problems and get the actual value but when I change page where is the first class and trying to get value of Temp_Mash_value, I'm getting only the default value for example: Temp_Mash_value = 25; not the actual which was set.
I can add that the Mash mash = new Mash(); is called at the begining and changing slider value is after that

```
//In one of my class I have:

Mash mash = new Mash();
//... some code...
//method with:
//I'm trying to get value of slider:
double test = mash.Temp_Mash_value;



//The second class:

 public partial class Mash : ContentPage
    {
        private double temp_Mash_value;
        public double Temp_Mash_value
        {
            get
            {
                return temp_Mash_value;

            }
            set
            {
                temp_Mash_value = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Temp_Mash_value));
            }


        }

        public Mash()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = this; 
            Temp_Mash_value = 25;

        }
    }
```

Comment: both pages need to use the same instance of `Mash` in order for this to work

Comment: Do you maybe know how to do this for this example? I have tried some solutions with instances and nothing help...

Comment: there are lots of ways to do this - the simplest is just to pass the VM instance from PageA to PageB on the constructor

Comment: Could it work ?

Comment: I have tried to make it with instances but still nothing. All the time I have received only default value.

Comment: @Rockmen7 It works for me.Could you show me more of the code you used.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to make your Mash to global static.

```
public partial class Mash : ContentPage
{
    private double temp_Mash_value;
    public double Temp_Mash_value
    public static Mash Instance;
    {
        get
        {
            return temp_Mash_value;

        }
        set
        {
            temp_Mash_value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Temp_Mash_value));
        }


    }

    public Mash()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this; 
        Temp_Mash_value = 25;
        Instance = this;
    }
}
```

then in other class you could get the value like:

```
double test = Mash.Instance.Temp_Mash_value;
```

Comment: Unfortunately it cannot be static, moreover I have few properties like Temp_Mash_value